# Error calculation from calibration data?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, measurement-error, measurement, calibration

Suppose I have the following calibration data from a measuring instrument:

```
| X_true (mm) | X1_measured | X2_measured | X3_measured |  
| ----------: | ----------: | ----------: | ----------: |  
|           0 |       -1.12 |       -0.69 |        0.18 |  
|           1 |        0.21 |        0.42 |        0.81 |  
|           2 |        1.18 |        1.65 |        1.35 |  
|           3 |        2.09 |        2.48 |        2.66 | 
...
```

I have three measurements per each true value. I can compute mean and standard deviation for the measurements per each true value to obtain, e.g. $\mu_i \pm 3\sigma_i$ with 99.7% confidence assuming normal distribution.

I would like to do a linear fit to obtain a calibration equation. Should I fit $X_{true} = f(\mu_i)$, or with all data $X_{true} = f(X^\prime)$, where $X^\prime = [X_1,X_2,X,_3]$?

How do I go about reporting the error (with 99.7%) for a given measurement (after calibration), e.g. $4.45 \pm 0.4$mm? Do I need to test for normality?